# Kentico 12 - unable to choose existing page template for new page of a particular type

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

What I have:

A custom page type called 'x'

A custom page template called 'Service'

A page of type 'x' whose page template is set to 'Service'

What I can't seem to do:

After creating a second page of page type 'x', (this page is a sibling of the first page) I go to change its template and try to find the 'Service' page template, but it is not listed in the 'Select page template' dialog.

Everything is checked in.

I haven't defined any scopes.

What could prevent my page template from being available in the 'select page template' dialog?
The 'Service' page template is also not listed when I modify the `'New page settings' > default page template` of the 'x' page type

To clarify, here's the page template dialog of the first page I created:
[image]

and here is the page template dialog of the second page I created:
[image]

Why can't I find the template from the second page?

Comment: Is it possible that the page template was originally created as ad-hoc?

Comment: How does the controller look (assuming you have one)?

Comment: Are you using portal engine or MVC development approach? Please, update your question as this is very important information and based on it you may get different answers - just to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm using portal engine, not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the portal engine development model, then you need to ensure each page template is added to the site otherwise it will not display in the page template selection dialogue when creating a page.

To check if a given the page template is added to the site:

1. Goto the Page Templates app
2. Select the page template in the tree listing
3. Select the Sites tab
4. Ensure the page template is added to the site

Comment: Thanks, but the page template is already associated with the site.